# How to convert Swing TreeNode to Apache Tobago TreePath?

Tags: java, apache, swing, tree

I have a Swing TreeNode (DefaultMutableTreeNode) and have to generate a Apache Tobago TreePath for each Swing TreeNode:

Swing Tree:

```
Root
    Node1
        Child11
        Child12
        Child13
    Node2
        Child21
        Child22
        Child23
    Node3
        Child31
        Child32
        Child33
```

Apache Tobago TreePath:

```
[]
    [0]
        [0,0]
        [0,1]
        [0,2]
    [1]
        [1,0]
        [1,1]
        [1,2]
    [2]
        [2,0]
        [2,1]
        [2,2]
```

Example:

```
  Input:  Child11
  Output: [0,1]
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance
Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example something like this:

```
public static org.apache.myfaces.tobago.model.TreePath convertPath(TreeNode node) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    TreeNode current = node;
    while (current.getParent() != null) {
        list.add(0, current.getParent().getIndex(current));
        current = current.getParent();
    }
    return new org.apache.myfaces.tobago.model.TreePath(list);
}
```

Comment: Hi Sergiy, 
this is a very smart solution. 
Many thanks for your help. 
Have a nice day.
Thomas